# Perl - copying directory from other machine to local machine

Tags: perl, ssh, scp

I'm trying to write a perl script which copies a directory with files from other machine to current machine.
I can use the `scp` command in shell but it requires a password. Also I don't have the following modules insatlled on my work area (and unfortunately I cant install them):

> Net::OpenSSH
>
> Net::SSH::Perl
>
> Net::SCP
>
> Net:: FTP

I do have installed `Net::SSH`

My mission is to copy the files from other machine to current machine. The main problem is that it requires a password to use `scp` on shell. Is there any elegant way to solve this problem?

Comment: [Crossposted to PerlMonks](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1210666).

Answer (score 4):

The elegant way is to use public key authentication.

If you really need password authentication, well, besides the ones you listed there are other modules which would allow you to automate it. Check if you have available [Net::SSH2](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SSH2), [Expect](https://metacpan.org/pod/Expect) or [IO::Pty](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Pty).

You may also be able to use use some `ssh`/`scp` client accepting the password from the command line or from an environment variable* as [plink](https://linux.die.net/man/1/plink), [pscp](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pscp) or [lftp](https://linux.die.net/man/1/lftp).

Another possibility is using the utility [sshpass](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sshpass).

(* Note that passing passwords in the command line or in environment variables is a very insecure practice!)

Comment: The "_public key authentication_" is the key, and I use `rsync` for transfer

Comment: Rsync for transfer is far superior to scp when most of the files are the same each time since rsync only copies the difference. Much faster. Especially on slow lines or large and/or many files. Rsync can utilize ssh (maybe to a special user on the server) or be set up as a rsync daemon on the server. Both makes it possible to control which directories are made available (read only or read-write) and which clients (ip check) can access. Learning the intricacies of ssh/scp and rsync takes some effort but is well worth it if file transfer is part of your job.