# Reading lines of a file into a hash parallel in Perl

Tags: perl, hash

I have thousands of files. My goal is to insert the lines of those files into a hash (Big amount of those lines repeats).
For now, I iterate through an array on files and for each file, I open it and split the row (Because each row is in the following format: `<path>,<number>`).
Then I insert into the `%paths` hash. Also each line I write into one main file (trying to save time by combining).

Piece of my code:

```
open(my $fh_main, '>', "$main_file") or die;
foreach my $dir (@dirs)
{
    my $test = $dir."/"."test.csv";
    open(my $fh, '<', "$test") or die;
    while (my $row = <$fh>)
    {
        print $fh_main $row;
        chomp($row);
        my ($path,$counter) = split(",",$row);
        my $abs_path = abs_path($path);
        $paths{$abs_path} += $counter;
    }
    close ($fh);
}
close ($fh_main);
```

Due to a lot of files, I would like to split the iteration at least half. I thought of using the `Parallel::ForkManager` module ([link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49221685/perl-copying-directory-from-other-machine-to-local-machine)), 
in order to parallel insert the files into a hash `A` and into a hash `B` (if possible, then more than two hashes). 
Then I can combine those two (or more) hashes into one main hash. There should not be a memory issue (because I'm running on a machine that does not have memory issues). 
I read the decontamination but every single try failed and each iteration was running alone. I would like to see an initial example of the should I solve this issue. 
Also, I would like to hear another opinion on how to implement this in a more clean and wise way.

**Edit**: maybe I didn't understand what exactly the module do. I would like to create a fork in the script so one half will of the files will be collected by process 1 and the other half will be collected by process 2. The first one to finish will write to a file and the other one will read from it. Is it possible to implement? Will it reduce the run time?

Comment: I don't think that you will get more disk IO by reading files in parallel. Also see your previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53691911/most-efficient-way-to-concatenate-thousands-of-files-in-perl , which has answers. Also, don't read the files line-by-line but read them in bulk (see your previous question).

Comment: @Corion Hey, I saw the answer and they helped me a lot but my engineer has suggested me to do it parallel because it should be fast. I'm trying to test it and then decide which implementation is better.

Comment: Please checkout my edit to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try [MCE::Map](https://metacpan.org/pod/MCE::Map).  It will automatically gather the output of the sub-processes into a list, which in your case can be a hash.  Here's some untested pseudocode:

```
use MCE::Map qw[ mce_map ];

# note that MCE passes the argument via $_, not @_
sub process_file {
   my $file = $_;
   my %result_hash;
   ... fill hash ...
   return %result_hash
}

my %result_hash = mce_map  \&process_file \@list_of_files
```